# Adding event listener to window, after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, addeventlistener

So I have a img that has onClick function

```
<img className="pointer pipette-icon" src={pipetteIcon} alt="" onClick={handlePipetteClick} />
```

My goal is: after clicking on this img I want to happen nothing except adding an event listener to my document and let's say log something. So first click on img, nothing is supposed to happen, second click is console log, and third, fourth etc. nothing should happen, unless I click again on img and then another click has to be console log.

I tried this

```
const handlePipetteClick = e => {
    document.addEventListener('click', console.log('click'));
  };
```

But console log happens on first click, how can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

So you juste want to add `listener` on click and remove it on click too.

Please add more code and codesandbox or thing like this for the next question.

But I found a solution for you.

You need to "remove" event listner after the event is run, to remove a event listner you need to keep the same function reference, it's why a put my function above the listener.

You can try thing like this :

```js
const handlePipetteClick = event => {
  const onClick = () => {
    // do what you want
    console.log('click');
    // remove event
    document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  };
  // add event
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
};
```

Comment: I wanted after clicking on img, to listen for second click and only then log 'click', in this solution log happens on clicking on img :/

Comment: Not at all men. How the log can be displayed before the event is defined :o

Comment: You call this function above `onClick` on image, the log with appear when document event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I get that on even clicks you want a console log.

```
let clicked = 0;

const handlePipetteClick = e => {
    let onClick = function(){
    clicked++;
        if(clicked ==2){
            console.log("click");
            clicked=0;
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
};
```